# SQL. Average entries per month

Tags: sql

I have some abstract entry in DB and it's creation date. How can I get average entries created per month?

**Edit:**

Table has Name field and CreationDate field.

Comment: Can't answer without being able to see the table definitions

Comment: And what RDBMS and version are you using would help too

Comment: I using MSSQL 2008 R2. But don't understand why you need it. I just don't know how to make this query.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) AS count, MONTH(date_column) as mnth
FROM table_name
GROUP BY mnth
```

Should work for you

Edit:

```
SELECT AVG(a.count) AS avg 
FROM ( SELECT count(*) AS count, MONTH(date_column) as mnth
       FROM table_name
       GROUP BY mnth) AS a
```

Comment: One more step needed: average those values by the number of months.

Comment: How can I get number of month and then average by them?

Comment: See new query above, hopefully i typed it out correctly. Just noticed your using MSSQL, this is for MYSQL but the "way" you do it should be similar

Comment: +1 - This will work fine on MSSQL as it is, no need of any modification

Comment: Yep. I get the "way". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

try this out

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(`datefield`)) FROM tablename
```

No subqueries

Comment: Oh. But it is not universal method. I mean if we have more than one year in created_date field there could be errors.

Comment: use DISTINCT(MONTH(`datefield`)-YEAR(`datefield`)) instead of just MONTH(`datefield`)

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(datefield), YEAR(datefield)) FROM tablename`

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(datefield)+ YEAR(datefield)*12) FROM tablename`

Answer (score 1):

hi using this query you will get the value

```
select avg(entry) as avgentrypermonth from (
select month(DateCreated) as month ,count(1) as entry from table1 group by month(DateCreated)
)q1
```