# Want to calculate avg value per user

Tags: sql, db2

I have data as follows

```
ID           Difference in days between 2 consecutive orders
abc.         2
abc.         3
abc.         7
xyz.         4
xyz.         5
```

I want the result as

```
ID .      Avg time difference between 2 orders
abc.      3(=12/4)
xyz.      4.5(=(4+5)/2
```

Comment: Can you explain `12/4`?

Comment: Shouldn't `abc` be equal to 4? That is, `12/3`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL. Average entries per month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271130/sql-average-entries-per-month)

Comment: I'm exactly doing the same thing as here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994862/date-difference-between-consecutive-rows

However I want the result to show me **avg of difference in days** per every account_number and **not** one row for every difference in days.


When I add avg(datediff(d1,d2)), i'm getting following error:

[Code: -112, SQL State: 42607]  The operand of the column function "AVG" includes a column function, a scalar fullselect, or a subquery.

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY14O.png

Answer (score 0):

you could use AVG and group by

```
select  id, avg(Difference ) 
from my_table  
group by id
```

Comment: avg(difference) is throwing an error.
I'm doing avg(timestampdiff(8, date1-date2))

Comment: you have error  ?  .. show  error message ..   wrong result  .. show a coherent data sample you actual result and the expected  result  ..

Comment: I'm trying to do something exctly as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288363/want-to-calculate-avg-value-per-user/55288400?noredirect=1#comment97306453_55288400

However I want the avg and not individual rows as in the above case.
When I add avg(timestampdiff) I'm getting the following error:

1) [Code: -112, SQL State: 42607]  The operand of the column function "AVG" includes a column function, a scalar fullselect, or a subquery.. SQLCODE=-112, SQLSTATE=42607, DRIVER=4.22.29